# Order of matrix in finite field GF(2)

Tags: matrices, finite-fields, binary

I was looking at George Marsaglia's paper `Xorshift RNGs` on xorshift random number generators where he states the following:

> In order that a nonsingular n×n binary matrix T produce all possible
> non-null 1×n binary vectors in the sequence β, βT, βT<sup>2</sup> , . . . for
> every non-null initial 1×n binary vector β, it is necessary and
> sufficient that, in the group of nonsingular n×n binary matrices, the
> order of T is 2<sup>n</sup>-1

Which appears to be equivalent to saying that, where k = 2<sup>n</sup>-1, T<sup>k</sup> = I and for all j < k, T<sup>j</sup> ≠ I. Equivalently, successive powers of T are periodic with period k.

Is there a way to determine what the order is of such a matrix, or even simply if the above condition is true, aside from checking if T<sup>x</sup> = I for **all** factors x of k (not only prime)? If T<sup>k</sup> = I and T<sup>x</sup> ≠ I for all factors x<k, the above condition would be true (I think), but does there exist a less lengthy test that would work for large powers k such as 2<sup>160</sup>-1, or large numbers with a large number of factors?

Comment: The order of $T$ surely needs to be $2^n-1$, not $2^{n-1}$ as you wrote. After all, there are exactly $2^n-1$ non-zero binary vectors of length $n$. Please check.

Comment: Anyway, to verify that the order is exactly $L=2^n-1$ it suffices to check that $T^{L/p}\neq1$ for all prime divisors $p$ of $L$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Yes, you are right on both accounts, my mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show that the order of a group element $T$ is $k$, you do not need to test all factors. It is enough to test for all prime factors $p\mid k$ that $T^{k/p}\neq I$ and that $T^{k}=I$. This can be done in polynomial time by iterated squaring (and some modifications of that), once you have the set of $p$. The hard part is getting the set of primes, currently no classical polynomial time algorithm is known for that for general $k$.

However you seem to be interested in a special $k=2^{160}-1$. This has some easy factors that can be computed by hand, e.g. $k=(2^{80}-1)(2^{80}+1)$, and computer algebra systems can factor such a "small number" as $k=2^{160}-1$ rather fast. So, using a computer algebra system built with these tricks verifying the order to be $k=2^{160}-1$ is doable. Here is a prime factorization of $k=2^{160}-1$:
$$
k=3\cdot 5^2\cdot 11\cdot 17\cdot 31\cdot 41\cdot 257\cdot 61681\cdot 65537\cdot 414721\cdot 4278255361\cdot 44479210368001
$$

**Note:** The quantum part of [Shor's algorithm](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shor%27s_algorithm) is a polynomial time quantum algorithm for order finding in groups. Currently that is of no practical relevance, as you will probably have not access to a sufficiently large quantum computer - as of 2022 noone has (officially).